# Split a string into two based on some special characters in android

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string like this:

```
[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"}]&@[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"},{\"ID\":0,\"Text\":\"Approved\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Freezed\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Cancelled\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"Completed\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Text\":\"Foreclosed\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Text\":\"UnApproved\"}]
```

I want to split my string into two based on &@ character combination like this:

```
 String [] separated=line.split("&@");
```

but when I checked the values separated[0] contains perfect first half of the string but when I checked separated[1] it contains full string without "&@" characters. I wanto separated[1] contain characters after "&@". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to get the second string with "&@" characters??

Comment: `split()` method doesn't work in the way you specified... My guess is that you are assuming it returns the full string because if you observer your original string, in your second part of string the first part is repeated...

Comment: @Chandrakanth No I want second string without &@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"}]

//&@

[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"},{\"ID\":0,\"Text\":\"Approved\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Freezed\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Cancelled\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"Completed\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Text\":\"Foreclosed\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Text\":\"UnApproved\"}]
```

that's your original String with line break around &@ to make it clear where it splits. As you can see the 2nd String starts with a repeated 1st String (without the closing `]`).
Your split works fine.

Comment: thx dly...my code was perfect but problem was with the string comming from webservice.

Answer (score 2):

understand the split function,it will take the input delimited and splits the string.

**String[] java.lang.String.split(String regex)**

Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

Regex Result 
: { "boo", "and", "foo" } 
o { "b", "", ":and:f" }

If you want the delimiter("&@") to be present.try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"}]&@[{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Capital Good\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"General Office Items\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Raw Material Purchase\"},{\"ID\":0,\"Text\":\"Approved\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"Freezed\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"Cancelled\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"Completed\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Text\":\"Foreclosed\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Text\":\"UnApproved\"}]";
    String[] resultArray = input.split("&@");
    for(int i=0;i<resultArray.length;i++){
        if(i!=0)
            resultArray[i]="&@"+resultArray[i];
    }

    for(String str:resultArray)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need regex something like `String mySpitedStr[] =  myStr.split("&|@");`

Comment: This will not achieve the desired behaviour specified in the question `I want to split my string into two based on &@ character combination`